# Talend to Salesforce: IOException: [LoginFault [ApiFault exceptionCode='INVALID_LOGIN'

Tags: soap-api, login, login-errors, talend

I am trying to connect Talend to Salesforce.

I complete the Salesforce connection settings in Talend:

1. User Id
2. Password
3. Security Token

And then try to test the connection, and I get this error message:

> IOException: [LoginFault [ApiFault exceptionCode='INVALID_LOGIN'

And the Salesforce Login Audit log says:

> Status:   Invalid Password

Yet I can log in via Chrome and the Security Token was generated today and copy and pasted into Talend.

What could possibly be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My password contained lots of special characters, which Talend did not seem to like.

After changing the password to something else, and getting the new security token, it worked.